# Перестановка в массиве по предикату

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм

Нужно переставить четные элементы в начало массива, а нечетные в конец.
Помогите, пожалуйста, написать код программы.

Comment: @Mary-Angel, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Имеем массив

```
a:array[1..20] of integer = (15, 12, 1, 3, 4, 9, 23, 29, 30, 10, 2, 14, 21, 34, 20, 5, 6, 22, 16, 40);
```

Его обрабатываем в цикле:

```
k:=1;
pos:=0;
for i := 1 to 20 do
if ((a[i]) mod 2) = 0 then
begin
  pos:=a[i];
  a[i]:=a[k];
  a[k]:=pos;
  Inc(k);
end;
```

После данной перестановки получаем сортированный массив, где первыми идут четные, вторыми нечетные числа.

Answer (score 4):

Можно с применение STL.

Положим, имеем массив int arr размером n

Вставляем хедер

```
#include <algorithm>
```

Функция определения четности:

```
bool isodd (int num) {
    return !(num % 2);
}
```

Далее реорганизуем массив:

```
partition (arr, arr+n, isodd);
```

А в С++11 можно еще проще с использованием лямбда-функции:

```
partition (arr, arr+n, [](int num)->bool {return !(num%2);});
```

Вот и все

Answer (score 3):

В C++ для этого есть алгоритм [`std::partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition).
Он реализуется следующим образом:

```
template<typename ForwardIterator, typename UnaryPredicate>
ForwardIterator partition(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, UnaryPredicate pred) {
  // ищем первый элемент не удовлятворяющий предикату
  while (first != last && pred(*first)) ++first;  // алгоритм std::find_if_not
  if (first == last) return first;  // все элементы удовлетворяют предикату

  // first указывает на конец последовательности pred(x) == true
  for (auto i = std::next(first); i != last; ++i) {
    if (pred(*i)) {  // элемент удовлетворяет предикату
      // перемещаем его в конец последовательности pred(x) == true
      std::iter_swap(first, i);
      ++first;
    }
  }
  return first;
}
```

Алгоритм `std::next(i)` возвращает `i+1` [для любой категории итератора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/481194/177684), алгоритм `std::iter_swap` эффективно меняет местами элементы, на которые указывают итераторы.

Как видно из реализации, элементы для которых предикат истинен сохраняют свой относительный порядок, а другие элементы - нет.
При необходимости сохранения относительного порядка надо использовать стабильную версию алгоритма, [`std::stable_partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition).

Применительно к четным/нечетным числам, предикат и вызов алгоритма выглядят так:

```
bool is_odd(int x) { return x % 2 = 0; }

int main() {
  int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
  std::partition(std::begin(a), std::end(a), is_odd);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

На каком языке программа? Логика следующая: Запускаете цикл по массиву. Проверяете условие - деление елемента на 2: если без остатка, то эл-т четный заносим в новый массив с четными, если нет, то заносим в массив с нечетными. В итоге будут 2 массива с четными и нечетными. После этого надо просто слить 2 массива и готово)

Comment: программа с++

Comment: Если уж делать, то правильно. Например, в духе поиска разделяющего элемента в quicksort. 

Двигаемся по массиву с обеих сторон к середине. Нечетный слева меняем (swap) с четным справа.

Алгоритм за один проход и на месте (никаких (тем более 2-х (@Barton !)) дополнительных массивов). 

Отрицательной стороной данного алгоритма является отсутствие устойчивости (stable) перестановки.

Answer (score 0):

Какой код? На чем? У экстрасенсов сегодня выходной.

1. Проверяешь элемент на четность и меняешь его с последним нечетным элементом в своем массиве

Answer (score 0):

Составь из исходного массива два массива: с четными числми и нечетными, потом выведи сначала четные, потом нечетные, в результате будет то, чего ты хочешь.

Answer (score 0):

В PHP можно использовать функцию пользовательской сортировки `usort()`. которую нетрудно настроить под перестанвку для элементов разной чётности и под сортировку для элементов одинаковой чётности.

```
$issue = [31, 42, 23, 35, 68, 13, 21, 34];
var_dump($issue);   
usort($issue, function($a, $b){
    $sub = ($a & 1) - ($b & 1);
    if($sub){
        return $sub;
    }else{
        return $a - $b;
    } 
});
var_dump($issue);
```

Результат:

```
array (size=8)
  0 => int 31
  1 => int 42
  2 => int 23
  3 => int 35
  4 => int 68
  5 => int 13
  6 => int 21
  7 => int 34
array (size=8)
  0 => int 34
  1 => int 42
  2 => int 68
  3 => int 13
  4 => int 21
  5 => int 23
  6 => int 31
  7 => int 35
```