# Зачем нужны функции std::advance, next, prev?

Tags: c++, итераторы

В стандартной библиотеке С++ есть функции `std::advance`, `std::next`, `std::prev`.
Зачем они нужны и в каких случаях следует их использовать?

Answer (score 19):

Функция `std::advance` появилась ранее функций `std::next` и `std::prev` еще в стандарте C++ 2003, в то время как последние две функции появились в стандарте `C++ 2011`.

Функция `std::advance` имеет следующее объявление

```
template <class InputIterator, class Distance>
void advance(InputIterator& i, Distance n);
```

Как видно из объявления, функция меняет тот итератор, который передан ей по ссылке в качестве первого параметра.

Однако, как показала практика, очень часто требуется создать новый итератор, который является предшествующим или последующим относительно текущего итератора. В этом случае приходилось прибегать к такому псевдо-коду (я использую термин псевдо-код, так как в нем я задействую ключевое слово `auto`, которое в стандарте C++ 2003 еще не имело того значения, которое оно имеет в стандарте C++ 2011), так как в общем случае итераторы за исключением итераторов произвольного доступа не имели операции сложения с целочисленными значениями:

```
auto next = current;
advance( next, n );
```

где `n` - некоторое целое число.

Например, рассмотрим задачу найти максимальный элемент во второй половине элементов некоторого списка

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

// ...

std::list<int> lst;

// инициализация списка некоторыми значениями

std::list<int>::iterator it = lst.begin();
std::advance( it, lst.size() / 2 );

it = std::max_element( it, lst.end() );
```

Так как функция `std::advance` имеет тип возвращаемого значения `void`, и она меняет переданный ей в качестве аргумента итератор, то ее неудобно использовать с алгоритмами. Требуются дополнительные объявления и предложения кода, чтобы вызвать какой-нибудь алгоритм. Например, вот как может выглядеть вызов алгоритма `std::rotate` для списка с использованием функции `std::advance`

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

// ...

std::list<int> lst;

// инициализация списка некоторыми значениями

std::list<int>::iterator middle = lst.begin();
std::advance( middle, lst.size() / 2 );
std::rotate( lst.begin(), middle, lst.end() );
```

Кроме того само слово `advance` не совсем удачное, когда дело доходит до вычисления итераторов, которые предшествуют заданному итератору. В этом случае требуется указывать отрицательное значение для второго аргумента функции, что может стать источником ошибок. Например,

```
std::advance( middle, -1 );
```

Из этого предложения трудно сделать вывод, является ли `-1` опечаткой или же это значение действительно выражает намерение программиста.

Такие имена, как `prev` или `next` более ясно выражают намерения программиста и делают код более читабельным.

Поэтому было предложено ввести функции `std::prev` и `std::next` в стандарт C++ 2011. Более того эти функции возвращают итератор, а потому их можно встраивать в вызовы алгоритмов. Они не изменяют итераторы, на основе которых функции возвращают новые итераторы.

Предыдущий пример вызова алгоритма `std::rotate` для списка теперь с использованием этих функций можно записать в одну строчку

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

// ...

std::list<int> lst;

// инициализация списка некоторыми значениями

std::rotate( lst.begin(), std::next( lst.begin(), lst.size() / 2 ), lst.end() );
```

То есть можно получать новые итераторы или выражения с итераторами "на лету", не засоряя код объявлениями промежуточных переменных, которые требуются лишь для вычисления аргументов алгоритмов.

Итераторы произвольного доступа можно складывать с целочисленными выражениями, чтобы получить новый итератор. Например,

```
std::vector<int> sequence = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

std::rotate( sequence.begin(), sequence.begin() + sequence.size() / 2, sequence.end() );
```

Однако этот код не является гибким. Если по какой-нибудь причине вы захотите использовать другой контейнер, который не имеет итераторов произвольного доступа, то вам предложение с вызовом алгоритма придется менять.

Значительно лучше будет если даже для итераторов произвольного доступа вы будете использовать данные обобщенные функции

```
std::vector<int> sequence = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

std::rotate( sequence.begin(), std::next( sequence.begin(), sequence.size() / 2 ), sequence.end() );
```

Особенно эти функции незаменимы, когда вы пишите шаблонный код для произвольного типа итераторов.

Обе функции `std::next` и `std::prev` имеют для второго параметра аргумент по умолчанию:

```
template <class ForwardIterator>
ForwardIterator next(ForwardIterator x,
typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::difference_type n = 1);


template <class BidirectionalIterator>
BidirectionalIterator prev(BidirectionalIterator x,
typename std::iterator_traits<BidirectionalIterator>::difference_type n = 1);
```

Поэтому эти функции очень удобно использовать, когда надо получить следующий или предыдущий итератор. Например,

```
std::vector<int> v = { /* некоторые значения */ };

auto after_first = std::next( v.begin() );
auto before_last = std::prev( v.end() );
```

Было бы логичным, чтобы функция `std::advance` также имела для второго параметра аргумент по умолчанию. Тогда вместо выражения, как, например,

```
auto it = v.begin();
std::advance( it, 1 );
```

можно было бы записать проще

```
auto it = v.begin();
std::advance( it );
```

И слово `advance` в этом случае соответствовало бы своему непосредственному значению.

Мною было сделано такое предложение  по включению в объявление функции `std::advance` значения аргумента по умолчанию равного `1` для второго параметра функции.

С данным моим предложением по изменению стандарта C++ относительно функции `std::advance` можно ознакомиться по этой [ссылке](http://cpp.forum24.ru/?1-3-0-00000076-000-0-0-1423215180)

Comment: Vlad, ей богу, сил хватило только дочитать до "Поэтому было предложено ввести функции std::prev и std::next в стандарт C++ 2011. ". Заочно +1, т.к. проблема действительно всегда была актуальна, и решена совершенно правильно. Но обратите внимание на [другую проблему](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1944/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0), и список литературы был бы тоже не лишним, раз уж Вам все равно не жаль наше здоровье (зрение я имею ввиду, конечно).

Comment: Гибкость с типом контейнера стоит того, чтобы инкрементить итератор по 1?

Comment: @Qwertiy Гибкость связана с тем, что операцию сложения с целыми числами поддерживают только итераторы произвольного доступа. Большинство стандартных контейнеров не имеют итераторов произвольного доступа..

Comment: Я понял. Но плата за эту гибкость - необходимость ползти по итераторам инкрементом.

Comment: @Qwertiy Это не так. Вы можете указать в качестве второго аргумента любое целочисленное значение. Для итераторов произвольного доступа функция специализирована и будет выполнять операцию сложения итератора с числом.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, а вот этого не знал, спасибо. Я думал, он просто в цикле сделает инкремент.

Answer (score 8):

Существуют различные [категории итераторов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/479234/177684), такие как `RandomAccessIterator` или `ForwardIterator`.

Категория итератора определяет [какие операции поддерживаются итератором](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.requirements):

- `RandomAccessIterator` умеет `it + n`, `it += n`, `++it`, `it--`, и т.п.;
- `BidirectionalIterator` может перемещаться только на один элемент:  `++it`, `it--`;
- `ForwardIterator` может перемещаться только вперед: `++it` или `it++`.

#### Перемещение на несколько элементов

Функции `std::advance`, `std::next` и `std::prev` упрощают перемещение между несколькими элементами для `BidirectionalIterator` и более простых категорий итераторов.

```
iter = std::next(iter, n); // Эквивалентно iter = iter + n;
iter = std::prev(iter, n); // Эквивалентно iter = iter - n;
std::advance(iter, n); // Эквивалентно iter += n;
```

Для `RandomAccessIterator` эти функции не дают никаких преимуществ, по этому нет смысла применять их вместо операторов `+` или `+=`.

#### Перемещение на один элемент

В требованиях к категориям итераторов, операции `++` и `--` определены следующим образом:

```
Выражение | Тип
----------+-----
++r       | X&
```

Там образом операции `++` и `--` определены только для переменных (l-value), и не определены для r-value значений, например результатов функций. По этому выражение вида `++f()` может не скомпилироваться:

```
++std::min_element(first, last) // НЕ РЕКОМЕНДУЕТСЯ: может не скомпилироваться
std::next(std::min_element(first, last)) // OK: next скопирует результат find()
                                         // и вызовет "++" у l-value
```

В остальных случаях нет никаких причин использовать `next` и `prev` вместо `++` и `--`.