# std::next vs std::advance

Tags: c++

Почему `std::next` дефолтно продвигает на 1, а `std::advance` - нет?

Comment: ну видимо потому next - следующий и это логично. А advance  -продвинуть и это не логично.

Comment: @pavel зачем тогда называть `next`, если он продвигает на любое значение?

Comment: Похожая тема, хорошо расписали [ссылка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/481194/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-stdadvance-next-prev)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я уже делал такое предложение комитету стандартизации по C++. Я описал данное несоответствие на своем форуме в теме [std::advance и std::bitset - два простых предложения по стандарту C++](http://cpp.forum24.ru/?1-3-0-00000076-000-0-0-1423215180) Номер этого предложения **№4369**. К сожалению я не отслеживал судьбу этого предложения. Формально предварительно в обсуждении оно было одобрено, но, как всегда, в комитете есть люди которые считают лишь собственные предложения самыми важными и ревниво относятся к другим предложениям. Поэтому я сейчас не в курсе, какова судьба моего предложения. Но явных причин не делать аргумент по умолчанию для второго параметра я не вижу и не встречал какие-либо серьезные возражения со стороны других оппонентов.

Answer (score 7):

Эти функции служат несколько разным целям и появились по совершенно разным причинам.

- `std::advance` - функция старая (С++98), которая предназначалась для унификации итераторов разных категорий в generic алгоритмах, и в первую очередь в тех ситуациях, когда итератор надо отодвинуть *более чем на один шаг*. С отодвиганием ровно на один шаг справлялись операторы `++` и `--`. `std::advance` была выполнена именно в виде именованной функции (а не перегрузки операторов `+=` или `-=`) именно для того, чтобы привлечь внимание пользователя к *потенциально неэффективной* операции и тем самым постараться исключить ее непреднамеренное использование. Аналогичные причины обусловили появление "парной" явной функции `std::distance`.
- `std::next` и `std::prev` - функции новые (С++11), созданные в частности для того, чтобы инкапсулировать идиому получения соседнего итератора *без модификации текущего*. Учитывая, что в общем случае к итератору не применима бинарная операция `+`, нельзя просто взять и прибавить к итератору `1`

  ```
  It it;
  ...
  foo(it + 1); // в общем случае - не сработает
  ```

  Для итераторов класс-типов в такой ситуации работает компактный вариант

  ```
  foo(++It(it));
  ```

  но он неприменим к итераторам фундаментальных типов, что в generic контекстах заставляет заводить дополнительную именованную переменную, т.е. выписывать что-то вроде

  ```
  It it_next = it;
  foo(++it_next);
  ```

  Это более громоздко, чем хотелось бы, и вводит в код ненужную именованную переменную.

  Функция `std::advance`, если обратить внимание на особенности ее интерфейса, тут никак помочь нам не может. Вот тут-то и приходят на помощь функции `std::next` и `std::prev`, которые скрывают подобные детали.

  При этом их наиболее востребованным назначением/употреблением является именно получение соседнего итератора. А возможность указать расстояние - лишь естественное расширение этой функциональности.

Другими словами, ответ на ваш вопрос в историческом ключе звучит просто: `std::advance` была создана *именно для сдвига итератора более чем на 1 шаг*, а `std::next` и `std::prev` заведены *в первую очередь для сдвига ровно на 1 шаг*.

Также учитывая, что `std::advance` может работать в обоих направлениях, было бы странно сейчас навязывать ей именно `+1` в качестве умолчательного аргумента.

Вполне может быть, что если бы изначально в C++98 функцию `std::advance` ввели именно с интерфейсом

```
template< class InputIt, class Distance >
InputIt advance( InputIt it, Distance n );
```

(т.е. с передачей и возвратом итератора "по значению", а не с передачей модифицируемого итератора "по ссылке"), то сегодня особой необходимости в `std::next` и `std::prev` так и не возникло бы. А если бы эти функции и появились бы, то возможно без параметра "расстояния".

Answer (score 5):

> Почему `std::next` дефолтно продвигает на 1, а `std::advance` - нет?

Потому как `std::next` как и `std::prev` **явно указывают направление** модификации. И наличие дефолтного значения - **лишь уточнение шага**.

Приписать же дефолтную модификацию для `std::advance` смысла нет, так как для данной функции позитивное и негативное смещения "равно-значимы". Если прописать шаг, то это автоматически приравнивается и к прописке дефолтного направления модификации, что не будет соответствовать аббревиатуре функции.

Comment: Сделать для `advance` смещение `0` по умолчанию, и все дела :)